# MacBook Air M1 Big Sur update failed

Tags: software-update, big-sur

I was updating my Mac to BigSur 11.5.1, but while downloading the update the network disconnected. Later on, I reconnected and resumed the download.

Downloading started from scratch. Question: has the *previous* download been deleted by the system or has it been stored as a file on my hard drive?

If so, where is the downloaded file and how do I delete it?

Comment: It was probably deleted. It’s best not to worry about such scenarios, since MacOS already deals with the leftover files.

Comment: You can list the files relating to an update, if they are present with the following terminal command : `sudo ls -al /Library/Updates`

Comment: @Jean_JD There is only two files present "index.plist" and "ProductMetaData.plist"

Comment: So, it's good news. All is right. ;-)